# Numeric to String conversion in Perl

Tags: string, perl, numeric, data-conversion

According to my knowledge when ever a string like

```
$a="120.43sunil"+5;
```

it will give a result like

```
$a=125.43
```

since string is not a number the "sunil" part will be omitted.
what if we get some thing like

```
$a="12fred34"*" 3"
```

will the string be converted to 1234 or 12034 ?
im kind a new to perl programming.

Comment: Seems strange that you would ask this as a question rather than just trying it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you turn on `strict` and `warnings` - like you really should - it will warn you.

Which is good, because it's a bad idea.

If you try your code, you'll see your second example gives:

```
my $val="12fred34"*" 3"   ;
print $val;
```

Gives:

```
Argument "12fred34" isn't numeric in multiplication (*)
36
```

`perl` is "finding" the 12, and using that, discarding the rest.

Your first example by the way - also warns:

```
Argument "120.43sunil" isn't numeric in addition (+)
```

But really - this is just a bad idea.

`perl` implicitly converts string to number when it can, but will warn if it can't. That's because in your second case, it's ambiguous. Should the text be zero? Ignored? Is this even one number, or is it two?

If you really need to convert to a number a part of a string, you should really parse the string first, and extract the values you want. That can be as simple as

```
$val =~ s/\D//g;
```

But it might be:

```
@vals = $str =~ m/(\d+)/g;
```

And if you really want to do fruity things with numbers and strings, look at [`dualvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#dualvar)*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Scalar::Util qw ( dualvar ); 

my $val = dualvar ( 120.43, "sunil" );

print $val,"\n";
print $val + 0; #force numeric context;
```

And whilst we're at it - don't use `$a` or `$b` - they are variables with a specific use in `perl` - `sort`ing. You shouldn't really use single letter variables anyway, it's a bad coding habit.

* I wouldn't actually recommend messing around with `dualvars` - they're really cool, but can make some really horrible code if used badly, which is what'll *probably* happen if you're "kind a new to perl programming"

Comment: I think that about sums it up! Shame you let `dualvars` out of its cage though

Comment: If someone wants new ways of shooting themselves in the foot, then who am I to argue?

Answer (score 1):

Without warnings and strict on, the first group of digits is converted to a number, after trimming leading whitespace.

This is easy to test and demonstrate:

```
$ perl -M5.010 -e 'say "12fred34"*" 3"'
  36
```

If you really need to use this, you want to turn off only the specific warnings/strict checks you want to turn off only in a small block of code where you do this.

Always use strict and use warnings.  And only disable the few checks you need to as narrowly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

String to number conversion in Perl works a lot like the C function `strtod`. That is, Perl expects optional leading whitespace, an optional sign (`+` or `-`), some digits (optionally containing `.`), and an optional exponent (`e` or `E`, an optional sign (`+` or `-`), some more digits).

As special cases, the words `NaN` and `Inf` (case insensitive) are also recognized as numbers.

If the string contains more characters after that, they are ignored but trigger a warning (if warnings are enabled). There's one exception: The string `"0 but true"` converts to `0` without warning.

If the string doesn't begin with a valid number, it returns `0` (and also warns).

Comment: `'0 but true'` is also a special case

Comment: 0 but true is where I might be tempted to break out Contextual::Return which lets you tell the difference between boolean and scalar contexts.

Comment: @Sobrique Contextual::Return is an awful idea and (like all Damian modules) should not be used except in toy programs IMHO.

Comment: Probably, but it is one way of handling 0 but true cases.